# Parse background job stops after 11 users

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

The background job that I'm writing is designed to iterate through every user and do execute code every time. When I run it, it only executes for 11 users, then stops. There doesn't seem to be any sort of Parse background job limitation that would cause this, so I'm not sure why it's happening.

The part of the background job that iterates through users is below, if any other part of the job is needed, I'll gladly add it. I get this message in the logs: `Reached max log messages per request, later messages for this request are truncated.`, so I can't even see in the logs what's going wrong.

Edit: When checking the Job status on parse, I see this error: [image]

Code:

```
    Parse.Cloud.job("MatchCenterBackground", function(request, status) {
    // ... other code to setup usersQuery ...
  Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
  var usersQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);

  return usersQuery.each(function (user) {
    return processUser(user).then(function(eBayResults){
      return matchCenterComparison(user, eBayResults);
    });
  }).then(function() {
    // Set the job's success status
    status.success("MatchCenterBackground completed successfully.");
  }, function(error) {
    // Set the job's error status
    status.error("Got an error " + error.code + " : " + error.message);
  });
});

// process user, return promise
function processUser(user) {
    // ... code to setup per-user query ...
    var matchCenterItem = Parse.Object.extend("matchCenterItem");
    var query = new Parse.Query(matchCenterItem);
    query.equalTo('parent', user);

    // easy way to share multiple arrays
    var shared = {
        promises: [],
        searchTerms: [],
    };

    return query.find().then(function(results) {
        // process results, populate shared data (promises and searchTerms)
    console.log('matchCenterItem query results:' + results);
    if (results.length > 0) {
        console.log('we have entered the matchcenteritem query');

        for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {

          console.log('we have also entered the loop inside the matchCenterItem query');
          // later in your loop where you populate promises:
          var searchTerm = results[i].get('searchTerm');
          // add it to the array just like you add the promises:
          shared.searchTerms.push(searchTerm);

          url = 'http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1';
          //push function containing criteria for every matchCenterItem into promises array
          shared.promises.push((function() {

            if (results[i].get('itemLocation') == 'US') 
            {
              console.log('americuh!');
              var httpRequestPromise = Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
                url: url,
                params: {
                  'OPERATION-NAME': 'findItemsByKeywords',
                  'SERVICE-VERSION': '1.12.0',
                  'SECURITY-APPNAME': '*APP ID GOES HERE*',
                  'GLOBAL-ID': 'EBAY-US',
                  'RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT': 'JSON',
                  'REST-PAYLOAD&sortOrder': 'BestMatch',
                  'paginationInput.entriesPerPage': '3',
                  'outputSelector=AspectHistogram&itemFilter(0).name=Condition&itemFilter(0).value(0)': 'New',
                  'itemFilter(0).value(1)': results[i].get('itemCondition'),
                  'itemFilter(1).name=MaxPrice&itemFilter(1).value': results[i].get('maxPrice'),
                  'itemFilter(1).paramName=Currency&itemFilter(1).paramValue': 'USD',
                  'itemFilter(2).name=MinPrice&itemFilter(2).value': results[i].get('minPrice'),
                  'itemFilter(2).paramName=Currency&itemFilter(2).paramValue': 'USD',
                  'itemFilter(3).name=LocatedIn&itemFilter(3).value': 'US',
                  'itemFilter(4).name=ListingType&itemFilter(4).value': 'FixedPrice',
                  'keywords': results[i].get('searchTerm'),
                }
              });
            } 

            else if (results[i].get('itemLocation') == 'WorldWide') 
            {
              console.log('Mr worlwide!');
              var httpRequestPromise = Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
                url: url,
                params: {
                  'OPERATION-NAME': 'findItemsByKeywords',
                  'SERVICE-VERSION': '1.12.0',
                  'SECURITY-APPNAME': '*APP ID GOES HERE*',
                  'GLOBAL-ID': 'EBAY-US',
                  'RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT': 'JSON',
                  'REST-PAYLOAD&sortOrder': 'BestMatch',
                  'paginationInput.entriesPerPage': '3',
                  'outputSelector=AspectHistogram&itemFilter(0).name=Condition&itemFilter(0).value(0)': 'New',
                  'itemFilter(0).value(1)': results[i].get('itemCondition'),
                  'itemFilter(1).name=MaxPrice&itemFilter(1).value': results[i].get('maxPrice'),
                  'itemFilter(1).paramName=Currency&itemFilter(1).paramValue': 'USD',
                  'itemFilter(2).name=MinPrice&itemFilter(2).value': results[i].get('minPrice'),
                  'itemFilter(2).paramName=Currency&itemFilter(2).paramValue': 'USD',
                  'itemFilter(3).name=ListingType&itemFilter(3).value': 'FixedPrice',
                  'keywords': results[i].get('searchTerm'),
                }
              });
            }

            return httpRequestPromise;
          })());
        }
      }

        //buildEbayRequestPromises(results, shared);
    }).then(function() {
        // process promises, return query promise
        return Parse.Promise.when(shared.promises).then(function() {

          // process the results of the promises, returning a query promise
          console.log('were in the when.then of promise');

          var eBayResults = [];
          for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
          var httpResponse = arguments[i];
          // since they're in the same order, this is OK:
          var searchTerm = shared.searchTerms[i];
          // pass it as a param:
          var top3 = buildEbayRequestPromises(httpResponse.text, searchTerm);

          eBayResults.push(top3);

          }

          return eBayResults;
        });
    });
}

// process matchCenterItem results to build eBay promises
function buildEbayRequestPromises(eBayResponseText, shared) {
    // ... code that pushes items into shared.promises and shared.searchTerms ...

  var ebayResponse = JSON.parse(eBayResponseText);
  var matchCenterItems = [];

  //Parses through ebay's response, pushes each individual item and its properties into an array  
  ebayResponse.findItemsByKeywordsResponse.forEach(function(itemByKeywordsResponse) {
    itemByKeywordsResponse.searchResult.forEach(function(result) {
      if (result.item){
        result.item.forEach(function(item) {
          matchCenterItems.push(item);
        });
      }
    });
  });

  var top3Titles = [];
  var top3Prices = [];
  var top3ImgURLS = [];
  var top3ItemURLS = [];

  //where the title, price, and img url are set
  matchCenterItems.forEach(function(item) {
    var title = item.title[0];
    var price = item.sellingStatus[0].convertedCurrentPrice[0].__value__;
    var imgURL = item.galleryURL[0];
    var itemURL = item.viewItemURL[0];

    top3Titles.push(title);
    top3Prices.push(price);
    top3ImgURLS.push(imgURL);
    top3ItemURLS.push(itemURL);
  });

  console.log('about to define top3 value');
  //Top 3 item info for every MatchCenterItem
  var top3 = 
    {
    "Top 3": 
      [
        {
        "Title": top3Titles[0],
        "Price": top3Prices[0],
        "Image URL": top3ImgURLS[0],
        "Item URL": top3ItemURLS[0]
        },

        {
        "Title": top3Titles[1],
        "Price": top3Prices[1],
        "Image URL": top3ImgURLS[1],
        "Item URL": top3ItemURLS[1]
        },

        {
        "Title": top3Titles[2],
        "Price": top3Prices[2],
        "Image URL": top3ImgURLS[2],
        "Item URL": top3ItemURLS[2]
        }
      ]
    };

    return top3;
}

// compare eBayResults to the users MCItems Array in their MComparisonArray object
function matchCenterComparison(parentUser, eBayResults) {   

    console.log('izayak habibi, eBayResults are the following:' + eBayResults);

    var matchCenterComparisonPromise = new Parse.Promise();

    // if the user has MatchCenter items, do this:

    console.log('ando ishal');
    if (eBayResults.length > 0) {
      console.log('yes the ebay results be longer than 0');

      var mComparisonArray = Parse.Object.extend("MComparisonArray");
      var mComparisonQuery = new Parse.Query(mComparisonArray);

      // Query that compares MCItems array contents to eBayResults
      mComparisonQuery.equalTo('parent', parentUser);
      mComparisonQuery.contains('Name', 'MatchCenter');
      mComparisonQuery.containedIn('MCItems', eBayResults);

      console.log('setup query criteria, about to run it');
      mComparisonQuery.find().then(function(results) {
        //No new items                      
        if (results.length > 0) {
          console.log("No new items, you're good to go!");

          //Add user to the "DON'T send push notification" channel
          ////////
          var installationQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
          installationQuery.equalTo('userId', parentUser);

          installationQuery.first().then(function(result) {
            result.set('channels', ["noPush"]);
            result.save();
          });
          ///////
          console.log('done updating channel');
        }

        //New items found
        else if (results.length === 0) {
          console.log('no matching mComparisonArray, lets push some new shit');

          var mComparisonEditQuery = new Parse.Query(mComparisonArray);
          mComparisonEditQuery.contains('Name', 'MatchCenter');
          mComparisonEditQuery.equalTo('parent', parentUser);

          console.log('setup query criteria again, about to run it');

          // Update MComparisonArray with new eBayResults
          mComparisonEditQuery.first().then(function(results) {
            results.set('MCItems', eBayResults);
            results.save();

            console.log('totally just updated the mComparisonArray, NBD');
          }).then(function() {
              ////////
              //Add user to the "send push notification" channel
              var installationQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
              installationQuery.equalTo('userId', parentUser);

              installationQuery.first().then(function(result) {
                result.set('channels', ["yesPush"]);
                result.save();
              });
              ////////
              console.log('done updating channel');

          });
        }  
      }); 
    matchCenterComparisonPromise.resolve(console.log('MatchCenterComparison Suceeded sen!'));
  } else {
    matchCenterComparisonPromise.reject({ message: 'No work done, expression failed' });
  }
  //return matchCenterComparisonPromise;  

}
```

Comment: Each background job is limited to 15 minutes, are you sure you are not hitting that limitation?

Comment: @sarvesh Definitely not, this happens 10 seconds into the function.

Comment: Don't see anything wrong with the code, can you post the rest of it?

Comment: @sarvesh Done. I've run the code again today, and after a small edit to the function, it got through about 30 users and stopped.

Comment: @sarvesh Namely, I added this if statement, in the event that result.item is undefined: 

`if (result.item){
        result.item.forEach(function(item) {
          matchCenterItems.push(item);
        });
      }`

Comment: You still have issues with the code. For example in matchCenterComparison you are resolving your promise before the save is completed. You will need to resolve after the save is complete. Also you might want to do this batches since as the number of users grow you will hit the 15 min limit.

Comment: @sarvesh Good point, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error, commenting out the `imgurl` values fixed the problem, since that variable won't always exist, depending on whether the user has items or not.

```
if (matchCenterItems.length > 0){

    matchCenterItems.forEach(function(item) {
      var title = item.title[0];
      var price = item.sellingStatus[0].convertedCurrentPrice[0].__value__;
      //var imgURL = item.galleryURL[0];
      var itemURL = item.viewItemURL[0];

      top3Titles.push(title);
      top3Prices.push(price);
      //top3ImgURLS.push(imgURL);
      top3ItemURLS.push(itemURL);
    });

  }
  console.log('about to define top3 value');
  //Top 3 item info for every MatchCenterItem
  var top3 = 
    {
    "Top 3": 
      [
        {
        "Title": top3Titles[0],
        "Price": top3Prices[0],
        //"Image URL": top3ImgURLS[0],
        "Item URL": top3ItemURLS[0]
        },

        {
        "Title": top3Titles[1],
        "Price": top3Prices[1],
        //"Image URL": top3ImgURLS[1],
        "Item URL": top3ItemURLS[1]
        },

        {
        "Title": top3Titles[2],
        "Price": top3Prices[2],
        //"Image URL": top3ImgURLS[2],
        "Item URL": top3ItemURLS[2]
        }
      ]
    };
```